# Prove by direct computation that $f^{[2]}(z) =\frac{1}{\pi i}\oint_{\partial D_1(0)} \frac{f(w)dw}{(w-z)^3} \text{ for } z \in D_1(0).$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, contour-integration

> Let $f$ be an analytic function in an open set containing $\overline{D_1}(0)$. Prove by direct computation that
>   $$f^{[2]}(z) =\frac{1}{\pi i}\oint_{\partial D_1(0)} \frac{f(w)dw}{(w-z)^3} \text{ for } z \in D_1(0).$$

I am not really sure how to start this question. **Any hints, or partial solutions?**

Comment: You might start with the power series for $f$...

Comment: You might use the Cauchy formula $$f(z) =\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\partial D_1(0)} \frac{f(w)dw}{w-z} \text{ for } z \in D_1(0)$$ to differentiate twice to get $f^{[2]}(z)$.

Comment: @xpaul Doesn't the integral formula have a $2\pi i$?

Comment: @AlJebr, yes, you are right.

Comment: @xpaul How would we differentiate the integral formula?

Comment: @AlJebr, use $$\frac{f(z+\Delta z)-f(z)}{\Delta z} =\frac{1}{2\pi i}\frac{1}{\Delta}\oint_{\partial D_1(0)} f(w)\left(\frac{1}{w-z-\Delta z}-\frac{1}{w-z}\right) dw, \text{ for } z,z+\Delta z \in D_1(0) $$ and then let $\Delta z\to0$.